# Labyrinth using ARM

Tags: arm

I have to do this exercise using a recursion subroutine:

Do a program that allows you to find the exit of a labyrinth represented in memory like a 15x15 matrix where:
-Value 2, is the objetive
-Value 1, is a wall
-Value 0, is a free space

The program receives an starter point (xi,yi) and bring back the point where the solution is (2).

I don't know how to do it, let's see if someone could help me.

Thanks

I have design the main program but I don't know how to do the subroutine to do what the exercise want.

Comment: See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.